# Should I change from buffered read to in-memory/tokenize on Android app for reading a 100,000 line file?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, tokenize, sortedmap

Currently I am loading a text file that contains 100,000 lines into a SortedMap using buffered reads.  Should I abandon this approach and instead load the entire file into memory and then tokenize by line feeds into the SortedMap?  Note, I have to parse each line to extract the key and create a per-key supporting object that I then insert into the SortedMap.  The file is less than 4MB in size so that fits in line with Android's in-memory file size limitations.  I am wondering if it's worth the effort to switch to the in-memory approach or if the speed-up gained just isn't worth it.

Also, would a HashMap be a lot faster than a SortedMap?  I only need lookup-by-key and can live without the sorted keys if necessary, but it would be nice to have around.  If there is a better structure than what I am using let me know and if you have any Android speed tips related to this issue please mention those too.

-- roschler

Comment: More Importantly you app give OOM error if you keep such a large data in memory

Comment: Not worth the effort. Loading onto memory requires reading the whole file also, but this is done by Android. I would go line by line with a Reader and putting each item in the Map. Notice that you are going to have a big data structure anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me why it would be simpler to load the entire file into memory and then tokenize. Reading a line at a time and parsing it that way is pretty simple, isn't it? While I'm all for loading things all at once when it *genuinely* makes things simpler, I can't see that it would be significantly easier here.

As for `SortedMap` vs `HashMap` - typically a `HashMap` lookup is O(1) if you don't have many hash collisions, but a `SortedMap` lookup is only O(log n) if there aren't equal elements. How expensive are comparisions compared with hash computations in your object model? With 100,000 elements you'll have around 16-17 comparisons per lookup. Ultimately, I wouldn't want to *guess* which will be faster - you should *test* it, as for all performance options. Look at the memory usage too... I would expect a `SortedMap` to use less memory, but I could easily be wrong.